Application of Reckless Endangerment
In there recent headlines: https://abcnews.go.com/GMA/Family/mom-arrested-after-son-reported-walking/story?id=115903965
An 10 year old walks to the store in rural GA in daylight.  The mother receives call from authorities that they are concerned about the son walking alone.  She indicated that she was not concerned.   They bring the son home and authorities return to arrest the mother 5 hours later.
TL/DR: In the video the mother says "last time I checked it is not illegal for a kid to walk to the store", the office replies "it is if they are 10 years old".  Mother is arrested for Reckless Conduct.
I don't have any children, however, when I was 10 I was rarely supervised by my parents.  My local elementary school has plenty of children (under 10) walking to school unsupervised.  The reporter indicates the son was not in in danger.  There is no mention of any problems.  I do detect a hint of obstinance in the mother, which usually results poorly with law enforcement.
What are the "Reckless Endangerment" requirements (i.e. age / context) that requires parents to supervise when a child goes outside for a walk?
Obviously, a two year old can NOT be left to walk to the store, however, I think it reasonable for a 10 year old to be outside and walk.  The article indicates: "failure to provide a child with adequate supervision necessary for such child's well-being", which seems overly broad.
I ask this question, because if there is a requirement, then how is the parent in this case supposed to know that the 10 year old is not allowed to walk to the store unsupervised?

Specific cases always have specific circumstances, which makes this question difficult. A generic answer would have to be generic and may not fit.

I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting, except for someone to quote the reckless conduct statute, which is very general and obviously isn't going to contain specifics like "parents can let their children go for a walk unsupervised if they are 11 but not if they are 10".  Whether it applies to the case at hand is what the jury will decide.

This seems to heavily depend on jurisdiction and US laws are very strict here. Here (https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/91726/from-what-age-may-children-walk-home-alone-from-an-activity-sport-in-germany/91733#91733) is a closely related question for Germany and it seems that even a 5-year-old could be fine on their own under suitable circumstances.

"when I was 10..." -- me too (I often walked to school in suburban Long Island). But times have changed. There's much more paranoia about child endangerment these days.
